# A problem involving spanning sets.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Given $S_1,S_2$ subsets of a vector space $V$ the objective is to prove

> 1. $\operatorname{span}(S_1 \cap S_2) \subseteq \operatorname{span}(S_1)\cap \operatorname{span}(S_2)$
> 2. provide an example where the '=' works and another where it does not.

I was able to handle (1), the problem arises in (2). I am not able to think about such examples.

$\operatorname{span}(S_1 \cap S_2) = \operatorname{span}(S_1)\cap \operatorname{span}(S_2)$ is true if we take $S_1,S_2$ as empty sets i.e. $S_1,S_2=\emptyset$, so $\operatorname{span}(S_1),\operatorname{span}(S_2)=\{0\}$ hence the 'equal' relation works.

Can anyone suggest a suitable example for the 'subset' relation ?

Comment: Continue in the same vein: take $S_1, S_2$ not empty, but disjoint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about $S_1=\{v\}$ and $S_2=\{2v\}$, with $v\neq0$?